# Identity 3.0 Entity Framework Core 1.0 Foreign-Key

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to wire up a one-to-many relationship between `Company` and `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`. In my `ApplicationUser` class I have:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
 {
    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
 }

public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...
 }
```

But I receive the `System.ArgumentException:`

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextFactory 1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type 'TContext'
```

Comment: So ... what is the issue you are having?

Comment: I receive the System.ArgumentException: ... Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextFactory`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type 'TContext'

Comment: When do you get this exception and how do you know it is related to the classes you show?

Comment: I wanted to include my DbContext for Company ... I get the above error when i try to migrate (Add-Migration). The context    public class CompanyDbContext : DbContext
    {
         public CompanyDbContext(DbContextOptions<CompanyDbContext>    options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Models.Company> Companys { get; set; }
    }

Comment: The question is really, how do I setup a one-to-many relationship between my  "Company" and  "ApplicationUser"?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the relation like this.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
 {

    public Company Company { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: What is interesting is on my Surface I get 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IDbContextFactory`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type 'TContext' on "Update-Database" but with the same project on my home PC it works just fine. I verified the dependencies on both machines and they appear to be up to date. I'm down for the count now.

Comment: It looks like IdentityUserLogin also requires a reference to Company.                                                                                                public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>
    {
        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }